# call class attributer in a class menu

Tags: python, class, attributes, call

I am probably making a big mess right now... But I want to create a menu that can activate different classes that holds attributes. What would be the easiest way to write this?

```
import replit

class Logistics_System(): 
    print("Welcome to Express Delivery")  
    user = []
  
    def menu(self): 
        while True: 
          print("")
          print("[1]. Add/remove/update: user to the system.")
          print("[2]. Add/remove/update: corporate customer.")
          print("[3]. Add/remove/update: private customer.")
          print("[4]. Add bike to the system.")
          print("[5]. Add Truck to the system.")
          print("[6]. Add Ship to the system.")
          print("[7]. Create shipment/order of items. ")
          print("[8]. Add Items to a shipment.")
          print("[9]. Update status of order.")
            
          print("")

          try:
            option = int(input("Choose from the menu: "))

            if option == 1:
              b.User()
            else:
              print("Program quits")
              break

          except:
            print("Wrong value!")
            self.menu()

b = Logistics_System()
b.menu()

class User(Logistics_System):
  user_list = []
  def __init__(self, first, last, id, adress, number, email, password, path):
    self.first = first
    self.last = last
    self.email = first + '.' + last + '@expressdelivery.com'
    self.id = id
    self.adress = adress
    self.number = number
    self.password = password

  def user_input():
    try:  
      first = input("First name: ")
      last = input("Last name: ")
      id = input("ID: ")
      adress = input("Adress: ")
      number = int(input("Number: "))
      if user_list >= 0:
        user_list.append([first, last, email, id, adress, number, password])
    except:
      print("Wrong value!")
```

I wanted to save these values to a csv file so I can remove data or add data when I need to

Comment: What are you trying to do with `if user_list >= 0:`? `user_list` is a list, not a number. And you need to write `self.user_list`.

Comment: Why is `User` a subclass of `Logistics_System`? A user isn't a kind of logistics system.

Comment: What is `b.User()` supposed to be? `User` is a class, not a method of `Logistics_System`.

Comment: You shouldn't hard-code the variable `b` in the `menu()` method. A class should not depend on the name of the variable containing the instance, it should use `self` to refer to the current instance.

Comment: `user_input()` needs a `self` parameter.

Comment: Why is `Logistics_System` a class in the first place? It could be a regular function. (And don't use recursion to implement a loop; use a `while` loop.)